# framework not found FirebaseAnalytics - Integrate SDK without cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, firebase

I get the below error . When i tried to integrate the Firebase in my xcode project. I integrated it without CocoaPods because i do not have admin right to install pods in my system. Please advise what has to be done. I followed all the steps correctly

ld: framework not found FirebaseAnalytics
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: I just walked through the Integrate Without Cocoapods instructions and it worked correctly. Unfortunately the question is way to vague and doesn't contain enough details (versions for example) to really help. Also, if you are not an admin on your development machine, you're going to have a number of other issues as well; not being able to install the current Xcode updates for starters.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot. Please advise.